# Jackson scala module writes None as null?

Tags: scala, jackson

Here is an example, demonstrating my problem:

```
case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Option[String])

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)

println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Foo("bar")))
```

This prints out `{"bar":"bar","baz":null}`, not just `{"bar": "bar"}` as I would want. Note, that `mapper.writeValueAsString(Foo(null))` returns `{"baz": null}` - so, the `null` fields are treated as expected, only `None` is problematic.

This works correctly for me with jackson `2.6.6`, but I just ran into this problem trying to upgrade to 2.8.8. Is this a bug in the scala module, or is there some new option I need to set to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Heh, took opening an issue with  the scalamodule guys to get an answer :)
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/325

Apparently, `NON_ABSENT` should now be used to do what I need rather than `NON_NULL`